# Edits to nvidia-xconfig not taking hold after restart?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, nvidia-settings

I'm building up a set of bash scripts to enable the overclocking of GPUs installed in my Ubuntu 16.04 system using the NVidia 384.98 driver.

For my first script I am trying to set the [`cool-bits`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA/Tips_and_tricks) (Bottom of linked page) option via `nvidia-xconfig`. My script is below

```
#!/bin/bash

# Secure required privledges
[ "$UID" -eq 0 ] || exec sudo bash "$0" "$@"

#== Enable overclocking in NVidia X settings (Replace/Add cool-bits for all GPUs installed)
# - 1 (bit 0) - Enables overclocking of older (pre-Fermi) cores on the Clock Frequencies page in nvidia-settings.
# - 2 (bit 1) - Driver will "attempt to initialize SLI when using GPUs with different amounts of video memory".
# - 4 (bit 2) - Enables manual configuration of GPU fan speed on the Thermal Monitor page in nvidia-settings.
# - 8 (bit 3) - Enables overclocking on the PowerMizer page in nvidia-settings. 
# - 16(bit 4) - Enables overvoltage using nvidia-settings CLI options. 
echo "============ CoolBits12_AllCards.sh: Started ============"
echo ">> Setting nvidia-xconfig cool-bits=12..."
sudo nvidia-xconfig -a --cool-bits=12 --allow-empty-initial-configuration
echo ">> ! Please restart for changes to take effect !"
echo "=========== CoolBits12_AllCards.sh: Completed ==========="
```

I am basically only running the command

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig -a --cool-bits=12 --allow-empty-initial-configuration
```

My initial `etc/X11/xorg.conf` looks as such

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "modesetting"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
    Option "AccelMethod" "None"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:5@0:0:0"
    Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
    Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:6@0:0:0"
    Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
    Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
EndSection
```

(Though mind you, I have ran the script a few times trying to get it to work, this might not be what it was originally. This reflects the script after a restart)

The output of running the script

```
============ CoolBits12_AllCards.sh: Started ============
>> Setting nvidia-xconfig cool-bits=12...

Using X configuration file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf".

WARNING: Unable to find CorePointer in X configuration; attempting to add new
         CorePointer section.


WARNING: The CorePointer device was not specified explicitly in the layout;
         using the first mouse device.


WARNING: Unable to find CoreKeyboard in X configuration; attempting to add new
         CoreKeyboard section.


WARNING: The CoreKeyboard device was not specified explicitly in the layout;
         using the first keyboard device.

Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "True" added to Screen "Screen0".
Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "True" added to Screen "Screen1".
Backed up file '/etc/X11/xorg.conf' as
'/etc/X11/xorg.conf.nvidia-xconfig-original'
Backed up file '/etc/X11/xorg.conf' as '/etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup'
New X configuration file written to '/etc/X11/xorg.conf'

>> ! Please restart for changes to take effect !
=========== CoolBits12_AllCards.sh: Completed ===========
```

And after running the script my `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` looks like so

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 384.98  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-02)  Thu Oct 26 15:56:05 PDT 2017

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "layout"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    Inactive       "intel"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "keyboard"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1060 3GB"
    BusID          "PCI:5:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1060 3GB"
    BusID          "PCI:6:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "True"
    Option         "Coolbits" "12"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "True"
    Option         "Coolbits" "12"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

I have verified, that after restarting the computer the first `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file contents listed first in the question are in place; the altered file/file contents did not hold.

**Why do my changes to the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file not hold?**

---

At some point I ran the script above twice prior to a restart, for completion sake, and potentially more information the output of the script is shown below

```
============ CoolBits12_AllCards.sh: Started ============
>> Setting nvidia-xconfig cool-bits=12...

Using X configuration file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf".

VALIDATION ERROR: Data incomplete in file /etc/X11/xorg.conf.
                  Undefined Device "intel" referenced by Screen "layout".

Package xorg-server was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `xorg-server.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'xorg-server' found
Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "True" added to Screen "Screen0".
Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "True" added to Screen "Screen1".
Backed up file '/etc/X11/xorg.conf' as
'/etc/X11/xorg.conf.nvidia-xconfig-original'
Backed up file '/etc/X11/xorg.conf' as '/etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup'
New X configuration file written to '/etc/X11/xorg.conf'

>> ! Please restart for changes to take effect !
=========== CoolBits12_AllCards.sh: Completed ===========
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem repairing screen tearing for nVidia. Even if I deleted /etc/X11/xorg.conf it would be recreated on reboot. The solution is to put your custom changes into:

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-nvidia.conf
```

A thorough write-up of nVidia modifications can be found [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA/Troubleshooting).

Comment: Should that file be non-existent prior to modification?

Comment: For me it was non-existent but there was a `10-intel.conf` file that I left in place. If in doubt backup the existing file before modification. Also you could experiment and keep the original 20-nvidia.conf and create a new 21-nvidia.conf.

Comment: What do the numbers refer to?

Comment: If it's like grub and udev then lowest numbers are executed first. My experience with nVidia is limited and forced by new laptop.

Comment: Ahh. // And this worked for me perfectly. // For future readers.. After continuing now, it looks like overclocking is tricky ( https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1010856/linux/how-to-force-performance-level-3-driver-381-22-with-gtx-1080-ti-/ ). It seems you cannot force the P states of NVidia cards by any means in the current NVidia drivers. This wouldn't be an issue if you could define OC settings for each P-state, but you can't, only one OC setting is applied for all states. So if you set the OC settings for P2, and the card jumps to P3, no fun will be had.

Comment: I thought p state was automatic? Mine goes to 0 under moderate load and 12 when idling. Or vice versa I'm on my phone.

Comment: That's the problem, it is automatic. Given that each P state has an associated (CoreClock, MemClock) tuple that increase monotonically with the level, along with OC settings that apply to all P states, you cannot properly adjust the OC settings for a given P state. // So if the card runs in P2 most of the time, at ~80% max performance, and you set the OC settings to be 100% max performance at P2 (ex +200, +800), then it jumps to P3, now the OC settings push the card to 120% max performance. // Also Nvidia P states reported in `nvidia-smi`/`nvidia-settings` are reversed under linux.. P0=P15

Comment: @KDecker I have a GTX 970M where p-states go from P0 to P12. The over clocking sounds complicated and I'm glad I have no need for that. I use Windows 10 for gaming.